# How to Deserialize response from rest service call

Tags: java, json, rest, deserialization, objectmapper

How to deserialize response from RestAPI call. I am getting MismatchedInputExceptionfor my below code.

Error I am getting is

```
PostService call failed! com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `ResponseList` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (String)"[{"code":"ABC1", "desc":"test"}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.Mis
```

Response format:

```
<200,[{"code":"ABC1", "desc":"test"}],[Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Tue, 04 Jan 2022 22:31:08 GMT"]>
```

My response body content is

```
[{"code":"ABC1", "desc":"test"}]
```

I used below code for deserialization

```
 ResponseList respList = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), ResponseList.class);
   System.out.println(respList.size());
```

My Model classes are:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseList {
     
    private List<ResponseDetail> tr; 

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResponseDetail {
    
    private String code;
    private String desc; 

}
```

Comment: `ResponseList` is an `Object`, not a `List`. It has a `List<ResponseDetail> tr` as field. Try deserializing the response body as `List<ResponseDetail>` directly.

Comment: List<ResponseDetail> ll = (List<ResponseDetail>) objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(),ResponseDetail.class);  I am getting same error for this also

Comment: ... you have to deserialize it as a `List`, not as a `ResponseDetail`. See [this article from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array) for details.

Comment: Thank you Turing85. It is working for below List<ResponseDetail> ll = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<ArrayList < ResponseDetail >>() {});